# Can a muslim play 8 ball pool video game?

Tags: halal-haram

I want to know that can Muslims play video games like 8 ball pool?

Answer (score 1):

As long as it dosnt take time for your ibadah its inshallah because it doesnt count on luck it counts on calculation

Answer (score 0):

**8 Ball Pool is Haram**

I myself played this game some time ago but stopped.

Why  ?

Because there is *Gambling * in it. Gambling/Betting is Haram and a great sin. There is a Hadith which says that even if we play a game without gambling  (but the said game is usually played by Gambling) , then that game is Haram, even without gambling.

8 ball pool is a video game that uses virtual money  ( money that's not real ). Nevertheless there is gambling still. Two players put forward a pool of money and the winner takes the money. That's the Gambling in the game.

This Gambling becomes a real sin if you spend real money on the game ; You can spend real world cash to buy in-game money and other stuff. Here you invest your money in a Gambling Game which is undoubtedly and elevated sin.

What's the point of your earning being halal if your spending is Haram?

So it's best to avoid this game.

Comment: I think it is mubah. Virtual money concept is not harmful or haram as real betting... And if it creates addiction that may harm your ibadah then you have to be aware about this game... But Chess is haram even though you play in online and it is clearly mentioned in hadith

Comment: Chess is Haram  ?

Comment: Yeah I read a hadith which mention " Pasha" which is translated into Chess. But you had better know various perspective of it in details.